# Inline Plots in Summary Table

Tags: r, knitr, inline, kable, kableextra

I want to create a summary table with small boxplots and histograms for each variable in a separate column (using kableExtra).

```
numeric_vars<-papeR::summarize(data, type = "numeric")
numeric_vars %>%
  kbl(booktabs = T, caption = "Numeric Variables") %>%
  kable_paper("hover", full_width = F) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down", font_size = 10)
```

My problem is that I can't manage to get the plots into the table. I suspect it is because I create the summary table first and then add them. Logically, though, that doesn't work. Does anyone have experience with inline plots and can help me here?

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Kaufpreis = c(560000, 823000, 890000, 1250000, 
452000, 375000, 455000, 850000, 390000, 1290000, 1076000, 517000, 
450000, 680000, 360000, 660000, 250000, 554000, 1120000, 555000, 
598000, 395000, 512000, 955000, 390000, 390000, 620000, 390000, 
665000, 885000, 695000, 820000, 492000, 465000, 1300000, 1050000, 
345000, 580000, 420000, 910000, 640000, 445000, 695000, 410000, 
258000, 119000, 630000, 258000, 633000, 820000, 360000, 495000, 
270000, 258000, 685000, 495000, 390000, 285000, 565000, 4e+05, 
750000, 1200000, 198000, 1450000, 598000, 550000, 775000, 595000, 
480000, 1650000, 930000, 820000, 590000, 565000, 735000, 690000, 
945000, 420000, 460000, 322000, 675000, 495000, 437000, 680000, 
345000, 735000, 565000, 740000, 398000, 1260000, 745000, 645000, 
780000, 328000, 1030000, 460000, 740000, 1350000, 950000, 1600000, 
590000, 1300000, 695000, 715000, 495000, 648000, 5e+05, 1370000, 
615000, 790000, 540000, 565000, 845000, 450000, 508000, 540000, 
595000, 470000, 595000, 590000, 460000, 280000, 245000, 860000, 
1200000, 395000, 1050000, 563000, 553000, 1300000, 1130000, 650000, 
860000, 1095000, 1370000, 450000, 495000, 690000, 550000, 670000, 
535000, 690000, 725000, 1200000, 940000, 650000, 1180000, 690000, 
1020000, 940000, 1215000, 670000, 980000, 1200000, 960000, 495000, 
960000, 595000, 795000, 667500, 1230000, 750000, 895000, 249000, 
795000, 396000, 455000, 1350000, 340000, 550000, 1150000, 1460000, 
870000, 478000, 539000, 667500, 630000, 1290000, 1290000, 750000, 
120, 690000, 590000, 920000, 580000, 498000, 245000, 395000, 
1290000, 367000, 495000, 675000, 470000, 590000, 770000, 560000, 
610000, 590000, 9e+05, 590000), Zimmer = c(5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 6.5, 3, 
4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
6.5, 6.5, 2.5, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
2.5, 2.5, 1, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 6.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 3.5, 5.5, 
5, 5.5, 3.5, 5.5, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 4.5, 
6, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 2, 4.5, 4.5, 
3.5, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 7.5, 6.5, 4, 6.5, 5.5, 
4.5, 3.5, 6.5, 4.5, 6.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6.5, 6.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 
4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 6.5, 
6.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 4.5, 
5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 7.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
3.5, 6.5, 3.5, 1, 4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 2.5, 5.5, 6.5, 4.5, 4, 5.5, 
6.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3, 4.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 2, 3.5, 
5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.5, 3.5, 4.5, 7.5, 6), Wohnfläche = c(142, 
105, 122, 135, 103, 79, 90, 127, 100, 116, 119, 111, 130, 138, 
82, 160, 53, 145, 116, 121, 130, 81, 111, 127, 81, 83, 115, 83, 
154, 120, 127, 181, 59, 120, 94, 174, 79, 108, 75, 135, 160, 
160, 170, 75, 48, 29, 111, 48, 79, 181, 100, 110, 96, 48, 125, 
110, 100, 70, 90, 84, 155, 150, 57, 127, 140, 62, 126, 140, 125, 
120, 150, 120, 92, 138, 154, 122, 103, 124, 144, 110, 80, 165, 
137, 168, 84, 110, 110, 155, 110, 144, 115, 136, 110, 55, 149, 
96, 107, 137, 120, 126, 92, 130, 130, 136, 165, 165, 89, 157, 
125, 138, 135, 178, 137, 130, 62, 135, 136, 140, 160, 1, 100, 
93, 127, 143, 150, 102, 115, 117, 117, 109, 120, 138, 110, 140, 
157, 130, 110, 123, 156, 100, 157, 123, 160, 161, 120, 125, 130, 
123, 156, 120, 114, 98, 140, 150, 113, 165, 113, 83, 144, 120, 
105, 100, 175, 88, 145, 115, 48, 127, 62, 156, 153, 127, 128, 
123, 155, 120, 152, 125, 125, 128, 100, 115, 165, 152, 115, 130, 
50, 96, 134, 73, 110, 139, 140, 110, 131, 140, 105, 112, 160, 
170), Baujahr = c(1996, 2013, 1991, 2012, 1966, 2014, 1987, 1988, 
1973, 2011, 2013, 2013, 1988, 1923, 1960, 1988, 1956, 2011, 2013, 
2013, 1988, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 1972, 1988, 1972, 1996, 2013, 
1992, 1990, 2011, 1993, 2013, 2012, 1970, 2014, 2015, 2010, 1993, 
1995, 1994, 2014, 1992, 1973, 2014, 1992, 2013, 1990, 1988, 1967, 
1970, 1992, 1978, 1967, 1973, 1963, 2003, 1998, 2011, 2008, 1959, 
1987, 1984, 1965, 2012, 1995, 1992, 1971, 1990, 1934, 1998, 1972, 
2015, 1970, 2012, 1992, 1980, 1993, 1921, 1955, 2007, 1995, 1975, 
2011, 1966, 1947, 1987, 2014, 1973, 2015, 1996, 1969, 2015, 1996, 
2014, 1967, 1992, 2014, 1998, 2001, 1972, 2015, 1955, 1988, 1972, 
2000, 2010, 2012, 2015, 1987, 2013, 1988, 2012, 2015, 1986, 1986, 
2001, 1974, 1993, 1995, 1996, 2005, 1988, 1996, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2003, 1992, 1982, 2014, 2000, 1988, 1967, 1995, 1984, 1962, 
1995, 1995, 1980, 2011, 1984, 2008, 1965, 1995, 1998, 1984, 2004, 
1969, 1989, 1988, 2014, 1955, 2014, 1983, 2006, 2013, 1972, 2013, 
1982, 1982, 2010, 1961, 1993, 2014, 2014, 1984, 1997, 2012, 1971, 
1982, 2014, 2013, 1996, 1971, 1971, 1971, 1950, 2002, 1964, 1950, 
1984, 2005, 1983, 1984, 2011, 1988, 1967, 2003, 1986, 1936, 2012, 
1910, 1984, 2013, 2008, 1974), GKODE = c(2662965.522, 2608948.214, 
2699911.913, 2708942.32, 2585095.936, 2625725.79, 2661997.121, 
2664063.073, 2596851.79, 2682264.584, 2608975.057, 2597087.496, 
2617960.423, 2602573.045, 2625153.114, 2663569.26, 2698413.718, 
2651534.62, 2687767.898, 2732795.22, 2719780.917, 2597075.052, 
2597087.496, 2590291.751, 2597075.052, 2665378.83, 2645220.874, 
2665378.83, 2602717.92, 2597075.052, 2611812.209, 2594446.44, 
2692386.699, 2711925.919, 2681170.684, 2729567.785, 2752753.405, 
2722130.87, 2722130.87, 2730619.727, 2722360.844, 2712301.924, 
2658968.885, 2722130.87, 2656300.586, 2594847.105, 2660839.344, 
2656300.586, 2608975.057, 2594446.44, 2581122.899, 2603536.779, 
2664743.17, 2656300.586, 2659945.592, 2603536.779, 2596851.79, 
2645404.051, 2609868.573, 2615806.166, 2601522.145, 2613010.163, 
2585995.554, 2681681.788, 2660886.438, 2602632, 2745024.768, 
2620663.201, 2761456.638, 2716754.19, 2768894.245, 2698333.923, 
2698634.884, 2688368.44, 2705611.513, 2614395.248, 2738650.012, 
2759825.884, 2727515.964, 2765654.957, 2663019.662, 2610950.484, 
2727163.184, 2601376.213, 2584184.81, 2612964.452, 2588735.786, 
2745850.616, 2666794.763, 2560484.026, 2613422.097, 2705611.513, 
2737633.85, 2673201.164, 2606719.896, 2605760.909, 2696797.693, 
2667537.263, 2673585.665, 2696862.053, 2698634.884, 2604534.224, 
2714801.185, 2705611.513, 2610950.484, 2661203.731, 2677403.687, 
2675839.158, 2753055.428, 2657397.465, 2758386.34, 2637152.069, 
2620164.252, 2617960.423, 2692950.421, 2758386.34, 2720376.832, 
2608848.612, 2649132.938, 2664986.21, 2661080.299, 2693900.746, 
2678367.032, 2609217.701, 2649832.619, 2646625.988, 2610387.931, 
2650802.038, 2649541.251, 2696996.692, 2696895.103, 2696265.257, 
2701884.735, 2686328.441, 2675839.158, 2617960.423, 2603536.779, 
2702451.167, 2613287.157, 2786044.799, 2712378.313, 2702451.167, 
2631316.33, 2669067.941, 2676440.575, 2666591.701, 2678072.729, 
2702451.167, 2720354.206, 2676440.575, 2739968.045, 2667448.799, 
2627604.488, 2649832.619, 2701391.091, 2610950.484, 2701391.091, 
2678587.996, 2637938.284, 2657505.769, 2681730.176, 2690234.446, 
2714072.084, 2723072.126, 2686421.644, 2737675.397, 2603086, 
2607718.926, 2666377, 2613287.157, 2677915.569, 2675471.147, 
2625236.706, 2729519.833, 2595081.218, 2657505.769, 2636993.022, 
2691234.234, 2691234.234, 2625236.706, 2687898, 2678080.249, 
2730946.073, 2685097.814, 2606088.101, 2608065.713, 2708964.134, 
2729708.844, 2681887.945, 2634795.585, 2603536.779, 2625111.49, 
2608848.612, 2621844.375, 2618171.594, 2619159.469, 2610229.36, 
2729879.686, 2634497.902, 2601716.594), GKODN = c(1198565.382, 
1229841.299, 1229214.436, 1116134.38, 1221544.704, 1231803.942, 
1256697.829, 1256036.353, 1227865.082, 1249506.172, 1229858.137, 
1227769.13, 1227716.246, 1249019.926, 1239652.589, 1242793.249, 
1260832.347, 1239161.854, 1252711.261, 1252437.189, 1232574.597, 
1227728.347, 1227769.13, 1214284.183, 1227728.347, 1247139.31, 
1244961.826, 1247139.31, 1252527.855, 1227728.347, 1180305.824, 
1220809.357, 1241930.084, 1234392.258, 1249059.823, 1279053.274, 
1227491.228, 1117868.49, 1117868.49, 1278024.378, 1277959.088, 
1264676.367, 1252387.842, 1117868.49, 1232407.524, 1114445.415, 
1258978.899, 1232407.524, 1229858.137, 1220809.357, 1194988.616, 
1203104.074, 1213992.74, 1232407.524, 1238993.275, 1203104.074, 
1227865.082, 1245432.725, 1264806.631, 1264690.483, 1258578.219, 
1263027.311, 1219300.705, 1225081.456, 1243873.656, 1128738, 
1188435.75, 1260072.228, 1258752.802, 1096890.25, 1188680.697, 
1260948.604, 1249577.858, 1284482.238, 1255508.793, 1239750.086, 
1185020.219, 1250870.791, 1254326.052, 1252891.212, 1244867.808, 
1224637.737, 1236461.035, 1228992.149, 1218213.975, 1176588.826, 
1216266.147, 1253714.774, 1240238.699, 1141538.323, 1260299.577, 
1255508.793, 1219676.345, 1236773.713, 1200853.025, 1230497.407, 
1240996.79, 1258053.287, 1186360.317, 1226278.364, 1249577.858, 
1197464.417, 1279532.365, 1255508.793, 1224637.737, 1264849.319, 
1256345.093, 1243389.697, 1210223.308, 1235682.338, 1256284.68, 
1173912.876, 1169324.525, 1227716.246, 1255354.952, 1256284.68, 
1257929.828, 1220008.224, 1237916.516, 1242499.758, 1270529.287, 
1181214.808, 1289228.362, 1255101.518, 1246310.773, 1242610.344, 
1263471.539, 1215610.154, 1212186.336, 1233387.224, 1261029.217, 
1243015.339, 1241943.882, 1257758.623, 1243389.697, 1227716.246, 
1203104.074, 1240944.29, 1184566.252, 1194612.573, 1233139.155, 
1240944.29, 1169887.863, 1219480.828, 1247319.67, 1222851.38, 
1245849.8, 1240944.29, 1275411.232, 1247319.67, 1185488.439, 
1256887.289, 1264369.762, 1246310.773, 1265110.56, 1224637.737, 
1265110.56, 1251885.174, 1234634.903, 1237380.905, 1222988.716, 
1246250.4, 1265043.38, 1252205.786, 1265130.415, 1268915.632, 
1128532, 1229776.073, 1150812, 1184566.252, 1240789.902, 1252619.319, 
1252399.167, 1278757.142, 1225791.874, 1237380.905, 1264791.796, 
1236829.763, 1236829.763, 1252399.167, 1290572, 1255087.07, 1223440.536, 
1254532.891, 1255251.175, 1251332.62, 1173857.396, 1278103.722, 
1226680.789, 1267788.604, 1203104.074, 1252433.492, 1220008.224, 
1260274.282, 1205663.674, 1249726.061, 1191069.479, 1278886.51, 
1264291.368, 1259077.437), dist_OEV = c(146.418832149328, 150.988440607186, 
84.7187562764425, 357.562199903722, 94.8885857835259, 412.487211273325, 
173.024414121361, 225.926943806883, 103.230997398999, 217.848448789579, 
151.418360901118, 117.839581279068, 255.612659007687, 541.796540687481, 
214.410148819879, 473.570228794882, 201.967462560083, 311.359762519146, 
252.585863668236, 216.052854924434, 106.71291064342, 116.249563925934, 
117.839581279068, 102.96506927111, 116.249563925934, 219.80697213686, 
757.010120244302, 219.80697213686, 162.905025781957, 116.249563925934, 
92.2542500757292, 184.493471561912, 127.716990478942, 1053.259442457, 
227.752916962643, 167.886805023459, 183.74452375219, 95.0612276377353, 
95.0612276377353, 32.3363790953301, 82.8662058984496, 374.946623487931, 
50.2225466201711, 95.0612276377353, 204.351799532021, 76.0092313472377, 
374.691572546055, 204.351799532021, 151.418360901118, 184.493471561912, 
126.495737702674, 116.846490392215, 69.1554517011601, 204.351799532021, 
433.892313931764, 116.846490392215, 103.230997398999, 557.896126735032, 
66.7992401904319, 74.478955719201, 295.39782495139, 256.311005011321, 
69.437655065467, 132.133678069009, 171.414498161648, 129.402472928457, 
367.482838135257, 606.646243197067, 142.973012306734, 134.063785564963, 
111.892286749474, 77.0910289527515, 201.359076328755, 39.875233466283, 
163.099129421238, 122.631696147295, 110.460527361488, 362.73341883125, 
59.3961951643924, 32.9289051290998, 179.588449261059, 164.256103158941, 
24.3193560974973, 137.91536379246, 280.701900109458, 459.716080401708, 
37.320388596397, 172.10137283585, 239.299633869502, 110.104400479749, 
176.416666837335, 163.099129421238, 120.158068913362, 73.0413531157657, 
200.537306856031, 149.402215278035, 239.492096631646, 266.284707668382, 
177.597648390967, 399.600992622544, 201.359076328755, 225.38601568187, 
949.896577238754, 163.099129421238, 164.256103158941, 156.530406381592, 
110.606883230791, 289.178880233199, 97.0717160040916, 437.907349183717, 
236.836014997575, 337.291678131749, 84.9105949160455, 255.612659007687, 
112.88815502524, 236.836014997575, 74.9269631574028, 115.961375983737, 
163.150011032792, 530.484467882046, 119.545262432296, 54.5020860151738, 
50.4893262780388, 139.76608216959, 456.389726757784, 205.342071870266, 
396.028462716959, 429.94917043748, 101.771242976418, 86.4036633482952, 
310.108709484178, 153.236637166353, 454.1523424459, 192.102109852965, 
289.178880233199, 255.612659007687, 116.846490392215, 261.694478331076, 
246.536618280214, 63.3356197570821, 129.305715241066, 261.694478331076, 
355.344950251035, 123.091490627798, 54.3760933221412, 30.4674547837771, 
202.455835778905, 261.694478331076, 121.429371487882, 54.3760933221412, 
92.4507152271601, 70.2128330291839, 271.12066462754, 456.389726757784, 
340.484783626282, 164.256103158941, 340.484783626282, 154.611624051939, 
265.316102159264, 338.437900339169, 35.3864328804327, 24.449272300004, 
165.617847637272, 87.0697977027839, 104.808716054437, 236.583699846344, 
57.0087712549569, 214.396354458255, 184.859406036047, 246.536618280214, 
214.726326669617, 270.035696473563, 321.472397454191, 148.080525569663, 
139.912041654705, 338.437900339169, 226.920783754938, 423.594009548062, 
423.594009548062, 321.472397454191, 89.6270048590267, 385.701927530929, 
176.401056190297, 169.650259289719, 108.956949415654, 214.936313286154, 
119.378016284493, 125.154742698736, 161.402464498103, 323.300799629445, 
116.846490392215, 220.25828057989, 115.961375983737, 212.632260367429, 
136.681509766284, 87.606105278123, 152.800729844327, 113.767054528311, 
222.504851695376, 164.735903205768)), row.names = c(NA, -200L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```